# LAStools (3D Analyst) scale factor application

Tags: arcgis-10.3, coordinate-system, lidar, lastools, scale-factor

I'm trying to use the las2las (transform) module from the LASTools toolset to apply a scale factor to an LAS dataset. The problem is that the client wants us to apply the scale factor from a known XY coordinate. Does anyone know of a good workflow to incorporate an origin point in LAStools?

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this on the command line (and assuming I understand what you're asking), I'd use the [-translate_then_scale_x and -translate_then_scale_y](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2las_README.txt). This will offset the point cloud by the translate amount, then scale it. Then you can translate it back using -translate_x and -translate_y.

So, if the point of origin of the scale is 1000, 2500, and the scale value is 2, you'd invoke,

```
las2las -translate_then_scale_x -1000 2 -translate_then_scale_y -2500 2 -i in.las -o out.las
```

That way, the points would be scaled out away from the new origin. Then you shift the origin back to where it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob. I'm not familiar with the command line, so I was just using the GUI with Arctoolbox. Is there a way to accomplish what you're talking about in this way? I tried to use the transform x, transform y, then scale x, scale y, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I actually don't have Arc, so I was hoping there would be an obvious way to do that in the UI. But it _should_ work if you do what you say you did... I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't. When you say it didn't work, what do you mean? Maybe describe exactly what output you want and how it's different from what you get.

Comment: It resulted in a shift over 100ft to the NE. I'm looking to horizontally match field-collected control points.